# where to place for loop in double sum to multiply an array

Tags: python, loops, numpy, for-loop

I have this following double sum, where my c-file (5x4 matrix) is multiplied with two arrays `g_T_np` and `g_rho_np`. However, my end result isn't just one number but another array.

Now, I'm asking myself where I could include another for loop so that every entry within my two arrays are multiplied instead of the whole array.

```
g_T   = [1,T,T**2,T*sy.log(T),T**2*sy.log(T)]
g_rho  = [1,rho,rho**2,rho*sy.log(rho),rho**2*sy.log(rho)]

g_T_np = np.asarray(g_T)
g_rho_np = np.asarray(g_rho)

c = np.loadtxt("c_file2.txt")

for n in range(5):
    for m in range(4):
        free = c[n,m]*g_T_np*g_rho_np

f = open('Free_Energy_Values.txt', 'w')
print >> f, 'Free energy:', free
f.close()
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: I'd like to calculate the Free Energy according to this formula.

**Formula to calculate Free Energy**
[image]

**C-File**
[image]

Comment: Could you clarify, what is the function supposed to return? Also what is `inner` supposed to be in each iteration?

Comment: hi @hlfrmn thanks for replying. The function should return 1 numerical value. both `inner` could be deleted since it's a left over from my testing

Comment: what is this single numerical value supposed to be? You have two arrays of size 1x5 and an array of size 5x4. What is it that you are trying to do in this function?

Comment: i added some pictures of the formula and my c file values to my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice, that the outer sum is from 1 to 4, and the inner sum is from 1 to 5. The simplest way to translate a formula into a programming language is to just put the same thing without optimizations.

The straight-forward way:

```
from math import log
import numpy as np


def F(T, rho):
    g_T = np.array([1, T, T ** 2, T * log(T), T ** 2 * log(T)])
    g_rho = np.array([1, rho, rho ** 2, rho * log(rho), rho ** 2 * log(rho)])
    c = np.loadtxt("c_file2.txt")
    total_sum = 0
    for i in range(4):
        for k in range(5):
            # we are traversing columns, not rows: notice [k,i], not [i,k]
            total_sum += c[k, i] * g_T[i] * g_rho[k]
    return total_sum


T = 1    # dummy value
rho = 2  # dummy value
print(F(T, rho))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That looks very nice and I can see how it works :)